# Apparent discrepancy between declared kernel version and boot entries

Tags: boot, kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running Ubuntu under wsl. Issuing `wsl.exe --status` in Windows (11) returns

```
Default Distribution: Ubuntu-22.04
Default Version: 2

Windows Subsystem for Linux was last updated on 27-Mar-22
WSL automatic updates are on.

Kernel version: 5.10.102.1
```

and `uname -r` from within Ubuntu says `5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`. But the `/boot` directory contains

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root      4096 May  4 20:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root      4096 May  4 21:01 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    260489 Apr 14 08:46 config-5.15.0-27-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    261613 Apr 27 14:06 config-5.15.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    261233 May  3 14:20 config-5.15.0-29-generic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4096 Apr 19 14:05 grub/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 May  4 20:29 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.15.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 118149011 May  4 20:29 initrd.img-5.15.0-27-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 118191763 May  4 20:28 initrd.img-5.15.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 118173389 May  4 20:29 initrd.img-5.15.0-29-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 May  4 20:29 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.15.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    182800 Feb  7 00:35 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    184476 Feb  7 00:35 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    184980 Feb  7 00:35 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root   6241791 Apr 14 08:46 System.map-5.15.0-27-generic
-rw-------  1 root root   6248105 Apr 27 14:06 System.map-5.15.0-28-generic
-rw-------  1 root root   6248105 May  3 14:20 System.map-5.15.0-29-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 May  4 20:29 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-29-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  11064224 Apr 14 08:47 vmlinuz-5.15.0-27-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  11081440 Apr 27 16:32 vmlinuz-5.15.0-28-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  11081856 May  3 14:32 vmlinuz-5.15.0-29-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 May  4 20:29 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-28-generic
```

which seemingly indicates that the current kernel version is `5.15.0-29`.

How to understand this?

And by the way, can I delete the `-27` and `-28` entries?

Answer (score 2):

`/boot` is not actually used under WSL2.  If you have kernels in `/boot`, it seems like you may have installed them via `sudo apt install linux-image...` or perhaps they were installed as a dependency of another package?  Mine is empty by default on WSL2 (22.04) (and all of my other distros as well), and only populated once I manually installed a different kernel image just now for testing.

Keep in mind that Ubuntu on WSL2 is really running inside a VM that you don't have access to (the "Virtual Machine Platform" feature in Windows).  This VM is what provides the kernel, and then Ubuntu is run in a "namespace" inside that VM.  If you were to install 18.04, 20.04, and 22.04 in WSL2, they'd all use the same WSL2 kernel rather than the stock Ubuntu kernels.

If you want to clean them up, best to use `sudo apt remove linux-image...` followed by `sudo apt autoremove`, I would think.  If that doesn't work, I think we'll need to figure out what package installed them as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I never installed any linux images myself. `sudo apt autoremove` removed the `-27` version; after that, `sudo apt list --installed | grep linux-image` still shows three entries, `linux-image-5.15.0-28-generic/jammy-proposed,now 5.15.0-28.29 amd64 [installed,automatic]`, `linux-image-5.15.0-29-generic/jammy-proposed,now 5.15.0-29.30 amd64 [installed,automatic]` and `linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-proposed,now 5.15.0.29.32 amd64 [installed,automatic]` - don't know when and how they were installed. Are you sure it is safe to remove them?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე In that case, they may have been installed as dependencies of other packages, and no, I probably wouldn't delete them manually.

Comment: Not just Ubuntu, all the WSL2 Linux distributions (and also Docker when installed) use the same instance of a Linux kernel. Everything runs inside a single VM.

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong Agreed, but since this is "Ask Ubuntu" and some are sensitive to WSL when it comes to discussing off-topic distributions, I try to keep my "examples" to Ubuntu.  I'll sometimes branch off and discuss other distros (and definitely on Super User, Stack Overflow, or Unix & Linux).